# How to deal with a field name with / in it when using SQL in R to make queries in HANA

Tags: sql, r, hana

I use the following code to link R to HANA, so that I can use SQL language in R to look at the data in HANA.

```
ch<-odbcConnect('HANARConnect',uid='***',pwd='******')
sqlQuery(ch, 'SELECT * FROM "SAPB1D"."/BIC/AZ_RT_A212" WHERE DOC_NUM=1046349 AND CALDAY=20101102 ')
```

The above code works. However, I have some field names with special characters like / in it. So I cannot use those names in WHERE part. For example, If my code is:

```
sqlQuery(ch, paste('select * from "SAPB1D"."/BIC/AZ_RT_A212" ',
               'where /BIC/ZR_NETVAL=9.76'))
```

Then I have the following information:

```
[1] "42000 257 [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] Syntax error or access violation;257 sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near \"/\": line 1 col 49 (at pos 49)"
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'select * from \"SAPB1D\".\"/BIC/AZ_RT_A212\"  where /BIC/ZR_NETVAL=9.76'"
```

I guess I should do something about the field names /BIC/ZR_NETVAL. But this is my first time to use SQL in R. I am sorry I cannot post a data sample here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enclose field names in double quotes (`"`) just like database names if they contain special characters or are not all uppercase.

```
sqlQuery(ch, paste('select * from "SAPB1D"."/BIC/AZ_RT_A212" ',
               'where "/BIC/ZR_NETVAL"=9.76'))
```